# Create a trigger-event after a tab becomes active in flutter

Tags: flutter

I use Icons as tab title in my app. I want the Icons to change once a tab becomes active. Is there a possibility in flutter to determine when which tab is active?
All I found was this: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs

This is my appbar:
https://pastebin.com/DuxTNCqN

and this is the tabclass

```
class NookTab {
  final Widget title;
  final Widget tab;
  final Widget body;
  final List<Widget> extraActions;
  final bool supportsSearching;

  NookTab({
    this.title,
    this.tab,
    this.body,
    this.extraActions,
    this.supportsSearching = false,
  });
}

class NookPageContext {
  final BuildContext context;
  final String searchText;

  NookPageContext({
    this.context,
    this.searchText,
  });
}
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: I added it. Can I somehow determine if a tab gets active?